How to sorting data from CSV in java by age,gender,division
I have a CSV file that has data about powerlifters.
I'm confused about sorting them by gender (from male to female), age, and division. I tried some code, but I'm confused about how to sort data by gender, age, and division from CSV.
When I found the code, the code, it wasn't running (an error).
Example data
MeetID,Name,Gender,Age,Division
0,Dawn Bogart,F,42,Open Senior
0,Destiny Dula,F,18,Teen 
0,Jessica Jenkins,F,32,Open Senior
1,Emanuel Moldovan,M,21,Novice
1,Jared Morey,M,36,MPF
5,Ryan Daining,M,25,Open

This is my code for read the csv file
 public void readFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            File theFile = new File(fileName);
            System.out.println("File path: " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());
            if (!theFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File not found!");
                return;
            }
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(theFile);
            boolean firstLine = true;

            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Read line: " + data); // Debugging line

                if (firstLine) {
                    firstLine = false;
                } else {
                    String[] datas = data.split(",");
                    myData.add(datas);
                }
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Total Data: " + myData.size());
    }

And I used insertion to sorting them by IS;
private void insertionSort(ArrayList<String[]> data, int columnIndex) {
        for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
            String[] key = data.get(i);
            int j = i - 1;

            while (j >= 0 && Integer.parseInt(data.get(j)[columnIndex]) > Integer.parseInt(key[columnIndex])) {
                data.set(j + 1, data.get(j));
                j = j - 1;
            }
            data.set(j + 1, key);
        }
    }


If you provide data as an image other people can not use it to reproduce the issue. And what is the actual issue? You didn't provide any actual detailed errors, logs or symptoms. You need to [edit] the question to provide an actual [mre].

You would be much better off making a Powerlifter class and sorting instances of that

start by creating a record to store the relevant data: for example record PowerLifter(String name, Gender gender, int age, String division) { }; then you can use the sort method of List with corresponding Comparator

Good that you added example data, but it is only one row - nothing to sort there.

When you have them in a List it is easy to sort them: (lifters by age descending) lifters.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Powerlifter::getAge).reversed()).forEach(System.out::println);

Thankyou for all the help

If you're going to homebrew csv unmarshalling (as opposed to using a proper csv api) a key step you can take is to include a method like public static Powerlifter valueOfCsv(String[] fields) method in your bean. You can then load a collection of Powerlifter with something like private static List<Powerlifter> load(String path) throws IOException {try (Scanner s = new Scanner(Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(path))).useDelimiter("\\R")) {return s.tokens().skip(1).map(line ->line.split("\\s*,\\s*")).map(Powerlifter::valueOfCsv).toList();}}

Simplify reading the file by learning about Java NIO and NIO.2 features, especially classes Path, Paths, File, and Files.
Identify your file.
Path path = Paths.get( "path to your folder" , "your file name" ) ;

Import all lines into memory.
List < String > lines = Files.lines( path ).toList() ;

Define a record to hold your data.
record Powerlifter( String name , … ) {}

Define a collection in which to put your Powerlifter objects.
List<Powerlifter> powerlifters = new ArrayList<>( lines.size() );

Loop the lines, parse, and instantiate Powerlifter objects. Collect those objects.
for ( String line : lines ) 
{
    String[] parts = line.split( "," ) ;
    String name = parts[ … ] ;
    …
    Powerlifter powerlifter = new Powerlifter ( name , … ) ;
    powerlifters.add( powerlifter ) ;
}

Next, define a Comparator, passing to Collections.sort. The double-colons is a method reference.
Collections.sort(
    powerlifters ,
    Comparator
        .comparing( Powerlifter :: age )
        .thenComparing( Powerlifter :: name ) 
);

FYI, in real work you should use a CSV library to do reading and parsing of the file. You have several available to choose. Ex: Apache Commons CSV.

All good advice, but I would add correct data types for the attributes and parsing string values accordingly.

@Bohemian I don’t want to do their entire homework assignment! I intentionally left some pieces for them to fill in.

@BasilBourque Thankyou so much sir for the help, i will try it

And of course thankyou guys for helping me, appriciate.
